# Submit Form Button in Streamlit

Tags: python, streamlit

I made a simple app which will take user input and save it into SQL database.
The form will be displayed once the user will click the Form button after log-in.

The problem is with the `st.form_submit_button`, even tho it is clicked it show's false and doesn't perform any task which is supposed to perform.

```py
if st.button("Form"):
    st.subheader("User Info Form")

    # name = st.text_input("Name")
    with st.form(key = 'user_info'):
        st.write('User Information')

        name = st.text_input(label="Name ")
        age = st.number_input(label="Age ")
        email = st.text_input(label="Email ")
        phone = st.text_input(label="Phone ")
        gender = st.radio("Gender ", ("Male", "Female", "Prefer Not To Say"))

        submit_form = st.form_submit_button(label="Register", help="Click to register!")

        st.write(submit_form)

        # Checking if all the fields are non empty
        if submit_form:
            st.write(submit_form)

            if name and age and email and phone and gender:
                # add_user_info(id, name, age, email, phone, gender)
                st.success(id + "\n" + age + "\n" + email + "\n" + phone + "\n" + gender)
            else:
                st.warning("Please fill all the fields")
```

Here is the code.
Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is from the `if st.button("Form"):` not `st.form_submit_button`. Initialize a session state for the first button. Streamlit button has no callbacks, meaning all the entered data will be lost after user clicks on `submit_form`, because the page reruns.

Also take a look at `age`, `st.number_input()` will accept a **float** by default and that is not appropriate in your case. `age` should accept only an **integer**, the catch is to add `value=0` as a second parameter to `age = st.number_input(label="Age ")` to convert the `age` input to an **integer**.

```py
formbtn = st.button("Form")

if "formbtn_state" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.formbtn_state = False

if formbtn or st.session_state.formbtn_state:
    st.session_state.formbtn_state = True
    
    st.subheader("User Info Form")
    # name = st.text_input("Name")
    with st.form(key = 'user_info'):
        st.write('User Information')
    
        name = st.text_input(label="Name ")
        age = st.number_input(label="Age ", value=0)
        email = st.text_input(label="Email ")
        phone = st.text_input(label="Phone ")
        gender = st.radio("Gender ", ("Male", "Female", "Prefer Not To Say"))
    
        submit_form = st.form_submit_button(label="Register", help="Click to register!")
    
        # Checking if all the fields are non empty
        if submit_form:
            st.write(submit_form)
    
            if name and age and email and phone and gender:
                # add_user_info(id, name, age, email, phone, gender)
                st.success(
                            f"ID:  \n Name: {name}  \n Age: {age}  \n Email: {email}  \n Phone: {phone}  \n Gender: {gender}"
                        )
            else:
                st.warning("Please fill all the fields")
```

`st.success(id + "\n" + age + "\n" + email + "\n" + phone + "\n" + gender)` is not properly concatenated and will definitely throw an error, so I suggest you use `f-string` like I did

**Note:** *To write a new line in streamlit you need **double-whitespace** before `\n`, take a glance at my `f-string` in `st.success()`*
**OUTPUT:**
[image]