# Study of the use of "while" with Streamlit

Tags: python, while-loop, streamlit

I'm studying the use of "while" in Streamlit and I'm having difficulty with the counter, I can't use it to create separate files for each time I repeat. Thanks in advance for your help!

I wanted the data entered to be recorded in separate files, but the counter I created to solve the problem of keys and creating new folders is not working.

```
import streamlit as st

# Título
st.write('# Cadastro de dados')

# Atribuições
cont = 1
numero = cont
button2 = False


while True:
    # Nome
    nome = st.text_input('Informe seu nome completo: ', value='', key=f'nome {numero}').strip()

    cont_nome = len(nome)
    if cont_nome <= 3:
        if nome:
            st.write('O nome informado é muito pequeno!\n')

    # Idade
    idade = st.number_input('Informe sua idade: ', step=1, min_value=0, max_value=150, key=f'idade {numero}')

    if idade < 0 or idade > 150:
        if idade:
            st.write('Informe uma idade válida!\n')

    # Salário
    salario = st.number_input('Informe o seu salário mensal: ', min_value=0, key=f'salario {numero}')

    if salario < 0:
        if salario:
            st.write('Digite um valor válido!\n')

    # Sexo
    sexo = st.selectbox('Informe seu sexo:', ('', 'Masculino', 'Feminino'), 0, key=f'sexo {numero}')

    # Estado Civil
    civil = st.selectbox('Informe seu estado civil:', ('', 'Solteiro(a)', 'Casado(a)', 'Divorciado(a)', 'Viuvo(a)'), 0,
                         key=f'civil {numero}')

    # Finalização
    button = st.button('Salvar')

    if button:
        button2 = st.button('Novo cadastro')

        st.write('\n\nSeus dados foram registrados com sucesso!\n')
        st.write(f'Nome: {nome}')
        st.write(f'Idade: {idade}')
        st.write(f'Salário: {salario}')
        st.write(f'Sexo: {sexo}')
        st.write(f'Estado civil: {civil}')
        st.write(cont)

        with open(f'Arquivos\{cont}.txt', 'w') as txt:
            txt.write(f'{nome} {idade} {salario} {sexo} {civil}')

    if button2:
        cont += 1
        pass
    elif button2 is False:
        break
```

Comment: It is better to use a form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Submit Form Button in Streamlit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74298499/submit-form-button-in-streamlit)

Answer (score 0):

each time you interact with the application, it runs the script from top to bottom, including returning the values of the variables at that point:

```
# Assignments
count = 1
number = count
button2 = False
```

It's not a code error... it's just that the streamlit works like this (see documentation)

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5l9COMQ3acc